# Format attribute value "android:drawable" not valid

Tags: android

I'm trying to create custom attributes to my button but I dont know which format I must use to images in attributes declaration...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="TCButton">
        <attr name="Text" format="string"/>
        <attr name="BackgroundImage" format="android:drawable"  />
    </declare-styleable>


</resources>
```

Error is in the format="android:drawable"...

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can use **format="integer"**, the **resource id** of the drawable, and **AttributeSet.getDrawable(...)**.

Here is an example.

Declare the attribute as integer in res/values/attrs.xml:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MyLayout">
        <attr name="icon" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Set the attribute to a drawable id in your layout:

```
<se.jog.MyLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    myapp:icon="@drawable/myImage"
/>
```

Get the drawable from the attribute in your custom widget component class:

```
ImageView myIcon;
//...
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyLayout);
Drawable drawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.MyLayout_icon);
if (drawable != null)
    myIcon.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

To see all options possible check the [android src here](http://code.google.com/p/idea-android/source/browse/trunk/src/org/jetbrains/android/dom/attrs/AttributeFormat.java?r=96)

Comment: looking at this again, it could be added that a faulty namespace declaration will not give compile time errors. In this example, it could look like `xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/se.jog.mob"` if `class MyLayout` is declared in `se.jog.mob`.

Comment: You should call `a.recycle()` when you are done using the styled attributes.

Comment: In gradle projects, custom schema should always be "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: The method setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) from the type View is deprecated

Comment: Yes, there is a question about the deprecation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947603/setbackground-vs-setbackgrounddrawable-android

Comment: Using integer didn't let me select from @drawable in the XML. I had tu use fromat="reference" and then it worked.

Comment: Not working on Android 6

Answer (score 51):

I think it will be better to use it as a simple reference:

```
<declare-styleable name="TCButton">
        <attr name="customText" format="string"/>
        <attr name="backgroundImage" format="reference"  />
</declare-styleable>
```

And set it in your xml like this:

```
<your.package.name.TCButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    custom:customText="Some custom text"
    custom:backgroundImage="@drawable/myImage"
/>
```

And in your class set the attributes like this:

```
public TCButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MembershipItemView, 0, 0);

    String customText;
    Drawable backgroundImage;
    try {
        customText = a.getString(R.styleable.TCButton_customText);
        backgroundImage = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.TCButton_backgroundImage);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(customText)) {
      ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextView)).setText(customText);
    }

    if(null != backgroundImage) {                    
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourImageView)).setBackgroundDrawable(backgroundImage);
    }
}
```

PS:
Don't forget to add this line for the root element of the layout you are using your custom view in

```
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

If you don't set this, you won't be able to access your custom attributes.

Comment: Custom backgroundImage attribute setting in your example is wrong. More like:

custom:backgroundImage="@drawable/myImage"

Comment: This is the best answer. When you use format="reference", you will see the dropdown list to choise resource at custom:backgroundImage="@drawable/myImage"

Answer (score 21):

From AOSP code, I found how google engineers declare `ImageView#src` attr.

```
<declare-styleable name="ImageView">
    <attr name="src" format="reference|color" />
    <attr name="scaleType">
        <enum name="matrix" value="0" />
        <enum name="fitXY" value="1" />
        <enum name="fitStart" value="2" />
        <enum name="fitCenter" value="3" />
        <enum name="fitEnd" value="4" />
        <enum name="center" value="5" />
        <enum name="centerCrop" value="6" />
        <enum name="centerInside" value="7" />
    </attr>
    <attr name="adjustViewBounds" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="maxWidth" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="maxHeight" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="tint" format="color" />
    <attr name="baselineAlignBottom" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="cropToPadding" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="baseline" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="drawableAlpha" format="integer" />
    <attr name="tintMode" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Above code is a sample and it can cover most case in our development.

Comment: Found the above helpful (<attr name="src" format="reference|color" />), Upvote.