# Passing Arguments to a compound view

Tags: android

This is part of my main xml layout. I have a compound view(SingleDrinkView) and I want to set a different src for my image button for each 'SingleDrinkView'.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/profilePhoto"
            android:background="#d0d0d0"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <com.ziepa.drinkparty.SingleDrinkView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                custom:drinkImage="@drawable/beer_icon"
                />
            <com.ziepa.drinkparty.SingleDrinkView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                custom:drinkImage="@drawable/shot_icon"
                />
            <com.ziepa.drinkparty.SingleDrinkView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                custom:drinkImage="@drawable/wine_icon"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
```

I've added a custom attribute, but I couldn't figure out a way to set it to my image button :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/singleDrinkImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="???" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"

        android:text="x0"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So I ended up trying to set it via code by fetching this custom attribute :

```
case R.styleable.SingleDrinkView_drinkImage:

  //This string contains "res/drawable-xhdpi/beer_icon.png"
  String drinkImage = a.getString(attr);

  ImageButton imageBt = (ImageButton) this.findViewById (R.id.singleDrinkImage);

  //createFromPath returns null.                
  imageBt.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(drinkImage));

break;
```

Hence I don't know what to do right now, I'm also not sure if there's a smarter way of doing it. I wanted to have the same custom widget with different 'settable' attributes so to speak.

Comment: The approach that you have is what I normally do. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: I can't set the imageBt drawable. The path seems good, but createFromPath returns null and therefore no image is set.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I just figured out that in attrs.xml instead of using format=string, it is format=integer.

Then within the switch case all that is necessary is to use the getDrawable method instead of getString. This properly formats the resource id of the drawable from the xml.

```
switch (attr)
{
    case R.styleable.SingleDrinkView_drinkImage:

       Drawable drinkImage = a.getDrawable(attr);

       ImageButton imageBt = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.beerImageButton);
       imageBt.setImageDrawable(drinkImage);

    break;
 ...
```

More detail here : [Format attribute value “android:drawable” not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487247/format-attribute-value-androiddrawable-not-valid)