# Android Selector Drawable doesnt work with attributes

Tags: android, drawable, selector-drawable

I am using attr to create a selector drawable for my project so that once i change theme colors, i dont have to make any change in the drawable file. I am using following libs:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Here is the source code for drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
</selector>
```

in this same code, if i replace attributes with colors defined in colors.xml file, the same drawable works.

Sample drawable with colors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/color_primary" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/color_primary_dark" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/color_primary"/>
</selector>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How a drawable can use color??? You have to pass drawable instead of color

Comment: android handle that part itself.. see the code for second drawable. It works. The problem is when you use attributes.

Comment: I guess you have to use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6108156/2715073)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, found the problem. There is a bug in android [pre-lollipop] OS which doesnt allow you to use attr in drawable. Here is the link to bug:

> https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26251

Android dev team has released a fix but it works on android L and above.For workaround to this problem, refer to following solution:

> [How to reference style attributes from a drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041537/how-to-reference-style-attributes-from-a-drawable)

Answer (score 8):

I encountered the same problem and as of 2019 it hasn't been resolved so you can't have an attribute referenced in a selector as a drawable. I will share the solution I got for the problem as I don't see it posted in here. I found it in the last comment of the [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26251) also referred by mudit in his answer.

The workaround is basically create a drawable resource that will be the one referring the attribute value.

To illustrate your case the solution would be instead of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
</selector>
```

you would replace the ?attr/* for a drawable resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/colorPrimaryDrawable" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/colorPrimaryDarkDrawable" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/colorPrimaryDrawable"/>
</selector>
```

The drawables would be defined as:

**drawable/colorPrimaryDrawable**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" />
</shape>
```

**drawable/colorPrimaryDarkDrawable**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" />
</shape>
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 3):

I dunno if it's still relevant to you, but I was struggling with the same thing and I think I have found a workaround (kinda). The direct use of ?attr/ is not working (working on api 21 and up, but even then it's not working with color selectors (only with drawables).

So I did it like this (giving you my own example).
Create an atribute in attr.xml

```
<attr name="nav_item_color_selector" format="reference|color"/>
```

Then in all the themes you're using, add the attribute like so (f.e. for the Light Theme):

```
<item name="nav_item_color_selector">@color/text_color_selector_light</item>
```

or for the dark theme(default):

```
<item name="nav_item_color_selector">@color/text_color_selector</item>
```

Now my text_color_selector.xml (both) look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true"
      android:color="@color/myAccentColor" />
<item android:state_selected="false" 
      android:color = "@color/myTextPrimaryColor"/>
<item android:color="@color/myTextPrimaryColor" />
```

and when I want to use them, f.e in tinting my custom image view, I use:

```
    <com.yourdomain.yourpackage.NavDrawerIcon
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:id="@+id/nav_item_icon"
    android:layout_margin="24dp"
    android:tint = "?attr/nav_item_color_selector"
    android:tintMode="src_atop"/>
```

You can also reitieve it programmatically by using TypedValue, like so:

```
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    Resources.Theme theme = context.getTheme();
    theme.resolveAttribute(R.attr.nav_item_color_selector, typedValue, true);
    XmlResourceParser parser = viewGroup.getContext().getResources().getXml(typedValue.resourceId);
    try {
        ColorStateList sl = ColorStateList.createFromXml(viewGroup.getContext().getResources(), parser);
        viewHolder.textView.setTextColor(sl);

    } catch (Exception e) {  }
```

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: thanks for the help but this solution is not feasible for me as it requires me to set background for each control in java code.

Comment: I understand. I don't know what you need to achieve, but if it's the background for a layout or a view, it can be set with ?attr referencing the attribute you created in xmL as well. Not necessarily in java. And even if it is in java, the point is you only do it once. Because once you get the attribute to every theme you use, it will read the reference and set the selector dinamically.

Comment: @daxgirl Do you have an example snippet of using TypedValue for `attr` values with `StateListDrawable` on pre-Lollipop?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem while using attributes for color in a drawable selector.

I solved it by making a **color selector** instead of a **drawable selector**.
Basically, make a new resource, with Resource Type as Color, which will be your color selector. Here, unlike with drawable selectors, you can use your attributes without issue:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="?colorBackgroundDisabled" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:color="?colorBackground" />
</selector>
```

^I named this selector_background.

Then you can use that selector:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/selector_background"/>
```

Comment: This works, if you move the selector to the color package in resources https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource

Answer (score -7):

In stead of putting a "?" Change it to "@"

Comment: It is not working with @. Any particular reason why you want me to change the ? to @. Generally attr are referenced via ? instead of an @ symbol.