# Unable to use ?customColor in drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-styles, android-color

I'm trying to define a custom color for my app's theme.
Here is how I do:

define custom attribute:

```
<declare-styleable name="ApplicationStyle">
    <attr name="colorWeekdaysBg" format="color"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Define an application style:

```
<style name="ApplicationStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextStyle</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorWeekdaysBg">@color/access_weekdays</item>
</style>
```

Set style in the manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/ApplicationStyle">
```

Use this attribute in the drawable xml:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:right="-1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="?colorWeekdaysBg" />

            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="100dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="100dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

But for some reason it does not apply my color to the drawable. It applies a transparent color instead.

One more strange thing is if I replace my `?colorWeekdaysBg` with `?colorAccent`, which is defined in the `Theme.AppCompat`, then it applies correct color.

So finally the question: Do you have any idea why it doesn't work, and how to fix it?

Comment: Where are u setting what's the color of colorWeekdaysBg? In a variable called "access_weekdays" in colors.xml ?

Comment: @Antonio exactly

Comment: Did you try use "@color/access_weekdays" in the drawable xml? Let's try unsulate where the app lose the color.

Comment: yes, that's how I was using it before I decided to move it to the theme

Answer (score 1):

As per answer give by **mudit** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30757188/9293029) it is a bug in the pre-lollipop OS.
 It is reported in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36941443).

**In the devices which have Android Lollipop and above OS version it will work fine.**

Check below code:

**attr.xml**

```
<declare-styleable name="AppTheme">
        <attr name="colorWeekdaysBg" format="color|reference" /> <!-- Or you can keep color only. It will be ok -->
    </declare-styleable>
```

You have to set the attribute in the v21 style file. **Might be you missed this one.**
**v21\styles.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorWeekdaysBg">@color/access_weekdays</item>
    </style>
```

Create two drawable files to get it work on all devices. One for normal i.e. pre-lollipop version and another for Lollipop and above i.e. v21 drawable.

**your_drawable.xml** In this you have to set color from the color file.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:right="-1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/access_weekdays" />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="100dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="100dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**v21\your_drawable.xml** In this file you can set custom attribute like you did.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:right="-1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="?colorWeekdaysBg" />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="100dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="100dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**your_layout.xml** In your layout you can give that drawable as below

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnTest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/your_drawable"
    android:text="Test Text" />
```

Now check the answers of your questions.

> But for some reason it does not apply my color to the drawable. It applies a transparent color instead.

- Because you may not have defined your attribute in **v21** `style.xml` file

> One more strange thing is if I replace my `?colorWeekdaysBg` with `?colorAccent`, which is defined in the Theme.AppCompat, then it applies the correct color.

- Android Studio displays color in preview but when you will run the application and reached on that screen your application will be crash with the Error inflating class error
  `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #68: Error inflating class Button`

> So finally the question: Do you have any idea why it doesn't work, and how to fix it?

- I think now you have got the idea that why it doesn't work and how to fix it.